# how to override onCreateDialogView() and add custom view inside dialogpreference

Tags: android

I am trying to **add custom view inside Dialog preference**, but I don't know how to override `oncreatedialogview`. Please help me.

```
@Override
protected View onCreateDialogView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflt = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflt.inflate(R.layout.numberpicker,null);
    if(view!=null){
        System.out.println("view error");
    }else{
        System.out.println("view ");
    }
    /*plus=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonplus1);
    minus=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonminus1);
    d   isplay=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    */return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to override the onCreateDialogView() method if you specify the resource in your DialogPreference class by calling setDialogLayoutResource(). For example:

```
public class NumberPickerPreference extends DialogPreference
{
    public NumberPickerPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.numberpicker);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're overriding the **wrong class**.

Here's the code we all want to make a new DialogPreference:

`public class MyCustomPreference extends DialogPreference {`

and like most of the time, we use the auto-complete to make sure we don't have any typing mistakes and to be nice and speedy programmers.

But Android Studio creates this import statement:

`import androidx.preference.DialogPreference;`

That's nice and all, but the AndroidX class does not have an `onCreateDialogView()` method.

Fortunately the fix is easy.  Just delete the 'x' from the import statement, giving you:

`import android.preference.DialogPreference;`

Because of the many different libraries, this sort of issue is common, and will get more and more common as things keep changing.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the onCreateDialog method and add

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout);

return dialog;
```

inside it